Autowire Interface with default implementation in Spring
I got an Interface with only one method that has default implementation
@Component
public interface ClockInterface {

    default Date currentDate() {
        return new Date();
    }
}

I want to inject that interface into some different service through it's constructor like that
@Service
public class Service {
    
    private ClockInterface clock;

    public Service(ClockInterface clock) {
        this.clock = clock
    }
}

But on running the application I got the message
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.api.app.application.Service required a bean of type 'constructor in com.api.app.application.ClockInterface' that could not be found.
Is there some elegant way to inject that Interface with all default implementation into a service?
I've tried to mark a ClockInterface as follow
@Component
@Primary
public interface ClockInterface {

    default Date currentDate() {
        return new Date();
    }
}

But it doesn't change anything

Where is the implementation class for that interface? Without implementation class, injection will not work.

The error is obvious. There is nothing wrong in this.

There is no implementation. I though that the default implementation of the only one method of the interface would be enough.

Nope. It won't work like that.

You're using a Date. Please don't do that. That class is crap. Use classes from the java.time package instead.

The error is very obvious and pretty explanatory.
Field injection with interface only works when you have a class that implements that interface and a bean is available in the Spring container.
Introducing default method in the interface won't help to make injection.

I've just added simple configuration for that interface
@Configuration
public class ClockConfig {
    @Bean
    public ClockInterface clock() {
        return new ClockInterface() {};
    }
}

